# Storing data in mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am pretty new to mvc projects, and I have such an issue:
I have a page where is represented list of projects this is main page where user is redirected after logging in, and he has to click "choose" button to go to other pages which will be related to selected project, for example employees who work on that project, list of managers, users and so on. User should not be able to access these pages while he did not select project. So i have to store somewhere ProjectId which is selected, and on each his attempt to go to another page check whether this id is set or not.
Is there any special way to store this id and check is it set or not, and redirect user, not just by writing pretty strange method and use it in the beginning of each get request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the selection in the `Session` object when the user makes the selection. When the user tries to go to any URL, you can check the value in the `Session` object, and deny if it's not set.